# Python pyodbc fetchmany() how to select out put to update query

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

I have code to `fetchmany()` that will output eg:10 records 
And i have added iterating value for each 0 1 2 3 4 5 for print statement , now i want user input 0 or 1 and it should select column. For those input so i can update sql record for those column

```
cur.execute("select events.SERIALNUM, emp.LASTNAME, emp.SSNO, 
events.EVENT_TIME_UTC from AccessControl.dbo.emp, 
AccessControl.dbo.events where emp.id = events.empid and emp.SSNO=? 
order by EVENT_TIME_UTC desc ", empid)
rows = cur.fetchmany(att_date)
n = 0
for row in rows :

event_date = row.EVENT_TIME_UTC 
utc = event_date.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)

utc_to_local = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
local_time = utc_to_local.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
 att_date = utc_to_local.strftime('%d:%m:%y')


 print (n, row.SERIALNUM, row.LASTNAME, row.SSNO, att_date, local_time)
 n = n + 1


seri_al = input("Copy And Past the serial number u want to modifiy: ")
```

this will output following Data

```
0 1500448188 FIRST NAME  03249 2017-07-19 17:01:17
1 1500448187 FIRST NAME  03249 2017-07-19 17:01:15
```

Eg:

```
seri_al = input("Copy And Past the serial number u want to modifiy: ")
```

instead of copying and pasting '1500448188' these numbers I want the user to only enter '0' and map that one and update sql query as for where clause serial number.

Comment: Please show your code and what you have tried already. Thanks!

Comment: updated the code can you help

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you already know how to use `input` to prompt for the user's choice. The only piece you are missing is to add items to a dictionary as you loop through the rows. Here is a slightly abstracted example:

```python
rows = [('1500448188',),('1500448187',)]  # test data
selections = dict()
n = 0
for row in rows:
    selections[n] = row[0]
    print(n, repr(row[0]))
    n += 1
select = input("Enter the index (0, 1, ...) you want to select: ")
selected_key = selections[int(select)]
print("You selected " + repr(selected_key))
```

which prints

```
0 '1500448188'
1 '1500448187'
Enter the index (0, 1, ...) you want to select: 1
You selected '1500448187'
```

Comment: thank you it worked perfectly fine 
If possible can you explained how does code works
    selections = dict()
    selections[n] = row[0]
does it append each row

Comment: @sw0rdf1sh2318 - `selections = dict()` creates a new empty dictionary. `selections[n] = row[0]` within the loop adds a new dictionary entry with `n` as the key and the first element of the row (`row[0]`) as the value. See [the documentation on dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for details.

Comment: Ok i got it now